# Textarea with ng-model is not submitting when using wysiwyg

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, ng-submit, trumbowyg

I tried to make a form using ng-submit. In the form there's a textarea that call wysiwyg (it's trumbowyg). When submit it, all form data are submitted but that textarea.

```
<div ng-controller='contactCtrl'>
   <form id="inquiryForm" ng-submit="contact()">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData.name" name="name" class="form-control" required="" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formData.email" name="email" class="form-control" required="" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea ng-model="formData.message" name="message" class="form-control editor" required=""></textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In app.js

```
.controller('contactCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.formData = {};
      $scope.contact = function (){
      console.log($scope.formData);
   }
}
```

As you see, I call trumbowyg by `editor` class in `textarea`. When  the form is submitted, textarea is not sent while other are. When I remove `editor` from the class, it's working well. Why is it not submitted when using trumbowyg?

Comment: change the `name="name"` to `name="message"` on textarea and see

Comment: well, apparently it's still not working after I change that. I updated my question

Comment: it is not sent because your textarea  is overridden by trumbowyg. You have added ng-model to `textarea` not to trumbowyg  .So anything you write inside trumbowyg, angular will never know. Hence no data binding to ng-model.

Comment: so, is there no way to make it working with trumbowyg?

Comment: https://github.com/lizardK/trumbowyg-ng try this

Comment: @PunithJain, tried it and it works. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**trumbowyg** is updating your html out side the scope of angularJs so use some plugin in like

[github.com/lizardK/trumbowyg-ng](https://github.com/lizardK/trumbowyg-ng)

so that angularJs knows what changes have been done to your Html.